# Create own operator ** in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

There is a generic class Vector which extends std::array, and a generic class Expression which defines the possible expressions of the Vectors.

For example:

Vector A({1,2,3});

Vector B({2,2,2});

and the expressions:

A + B;

A * B;

A - B;

A / B;

Now I need this expression A ** B which returns a double as the scalar-production of two vectors A and B, the result must be: 2+4+6=12. The problem is the implementation of operator**!!!

How can i write this operator** ?

My Idea is to overload the dereference operator* of Vector which returns a pointer and then overload the struct-Mul oder multiply operator* ... couldn't solve this error:

"no suitable conversion function from "Expression< ... >" to "double" exists"

```
template<typename Left, typename Op, typename Right> class Expression {
    const Left& m_left;
    const Right& m_right;

public:
    typedef typename Left::value_type value_type;

    // Standard constructor
    Expression(const Left& l, const Right& r) : m_left{ l }, m_right{ r } {}

    size_t size() const {
        return m_left.size();
    }

    value_type operator[](int i) const {
        return Op::apply(m_left[i], m_right[i]);
    }
};

struct Mul {
    template<typename T> static T apply(T l, T r) {
        return l * r;
    }
};

template<typename Left, typename Right>
Expression<Left, Mul, Right> operator*(const Left& l, const Right& r) {
    return Expression<Left, Mul, Right>(l, r);
}

.......................

// Class Vector extends std::array
template<class T, size_t S> class Vector : public array<T, S> {

public:
    // Standard constructor
    Vector<T, S>(array<T, S>&& a) : array<T, S>(a) {}

    // Initializerlist constructor
    Vector(const initializer_list<T>& data) {
        size_t s = __min(data.size(), S);
        auto it = data.begin();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
            this->at(i) = *it++;
    }
};

.....................................

int main {

    Vector<double, 5> A({ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    Vector<double, 5> B({ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 });
    Vector<double, 5> C;
    C = A * B; // is a Vector: [6, 9, 12, 15, 18] and it works.

    double d = A**B;  // but this one does not work, the error message is: "no suitable conversion function from "Expression<Vector<double, 5U>, Mul, Vector<double, 5U> *>" to "double" exists"

    cout << d << endl; // must give me: 60
}
```

Comment: You do it like this: `dot(A, B)`. Which misguided soul denotes the scalar product with `**`?!!!

Comment: yeah, you're right! but this is a homework from the school :( it must be like that !!!

Comment: You need to tell that this is a homework and that you must implement this exactly as stated directly in the question.

Comment: Reopening, this question is not about implementing `**` for built in types and it is not impossible to do what is being requested.

Comment: There is no built-in operator `**`, so you can't overload it. Any workaround that you may come up with that lets you use `**` will also work if you call it with `* *`. This is a weird and misleading assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct V
{
  struct Vhelper
  {
   Vhelper(const V& v) : v(v) {}
   const V& v; 
  };

  V operator*(const V&) const {
     cout << "* called\n";
     return V();
  }
  double operator*(const Vhelper&) const {
     cout << "** called\n";
     return 42;
  }
  Vhelper operator*() { return Vhelper(*this); }
};

int main() {
    V a, b, c;
    a = b * c;
    double d = b ** c;
    return 0;
}
```

but you should forget it's ever possible right after your work is graded. Never do this in real code.

This is not a full fledged `operator**` because it cannot be used in all contexts a real `**` operator could have been used (and if you want to use it for the power operation, it has wrong precedence and associativity). But it should be OK for a little fun learning project.